# how to resolve angular material Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi'?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular project and I'm getting this error when I insert `<mat-icon>` and `<mat-form-field>`.

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.9.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

### Code

```
<mat-form-field>
 <div class="formInput">
     <input matInput size="30"  class="gen-style" id="password" placeholder="Password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="password" >
       <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>
```

### Error

```
 ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/coercion' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/coercion' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/keycodes' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/platform' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/platform' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/rxjs' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/rxjs' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
ERROR in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/gitlab repos/lms-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple.d.ts (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve @angular/cdk/bidi relative to C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/gitlab repos/lms-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts., resolving symbol MatCommonModule in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/gitlab repos/lms-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol MatCommonModule in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/gitlab repos/lms-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts
    at syntaxError (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:240:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:493:24)
ERROR in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/gitlab repos/lms-dashboard/src/app/user-management/user-management.component.ts (7,10): Module '"console"' has no exported member 'timeStamp'.
ERROR in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/gitlab repos/lms-dashboard/src/app/real-estate-lms/real-estate-details/real-estate-details.component.ts (427,31): Argument of type 'string | number | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.    
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
ERROR in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/gitlab repos/lms-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple-renderer.d.ts (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.

webpack: Failed to compile.
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

Comment: In general: Consider an update of your package.json. `@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8` is already outdatet for a long time. See https://angular.io/cli/update

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you get `module not found` error messages in Angular, it means that a module is missing.

So you need to install the missing modules in node js through npm packages tool. Try installing them with this command `npm install package-name`.

After installing the missing modules, check your `../node_modules` path. There should be a folder created inside of it with the name of the module you just installed.

Answer (score 0):

before trying steps make cdk version in package.json for [**2.0.0-beta.12**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cdk/v/2.0.0-beta.12)

after editing the version try the following steps :

1 - Clear npm cache

> npm cache clean --force

2 - remove npm folder

3 - npm install